# Take field values in an array and put them in flutter

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase array and in it are two string values I want to take those string values and put them on a flutter card that is in a ListView.builder but each string value has to be in a separate card. The item count is the length of the firebase array because there are going to be more than 2 string values in the array. I just want to make each value of the array in separate cards.

[image: As you see it shows the whole array]
[image: Just focus on the items array those are the two string values that I want in the flutter card]

Comment: Have you looked a bit into the documentation? I guess not, because you are lacking important info like (1) one time read or continuous stream (2) how do you manage state. Maybe you have a look, try a few things and come back with specific questions

Comment: Why are you not creating separate collection in the same document itself instead of creating an array and making it difficult and bulky for yourself to develop an streambuilder for the same ?

Comment: I made it a collection now what do I do

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(userId).snapshots().listen((doc) {
 images = [ for(var path in doc.get("images")) path as String ];
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to put it

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Generally, you want to use that in your [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) solution.